# BASH: comparing strings, one from a file, one in my program, if statement always is true

Tags: bash, scripting

So I have this block of code. Basically, I'm taking file $i, checking if it's got content or not, checking if I can read it, if I can open it, grab the first line and see if it's a bash file. When I run this every time on a non-empty file, it was registers as true and echo's bash.

```
            ## File is empty or not
            if [[ -s $i ]]
            then
                ## Can we read the file 
                if [[ -r $i ]]
                then
                    ## File has content
                    if [[ $(head -n 1 $i) = "#! /bin/bash" ]]
                    then
                        echo -n " bash"
                    fi
                fi
            else
                ## file does not have content
                echo -n " empty"
            fi
```

This is what does the check of if it's bash:

```
if [[ $(head -n 1 $i) = "#! /bin/bash" ]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `[[` with `[` and enclose `$(head -n 1 $i)` in quotes.

`[[` is itself an operator that tests its contents.

Comment: @Snow_Mac Strange this worked when the code I posted below, which matches yours exactly, worked. Would really like to know why.

Comment: @b1naryj Did you try the false case (that is, when the file does _not_ start with "#test")?

Comment: @'Adam Liss' Yes and it also worked. Couldn't find anything wrong with it. I'm on OSX 10.7, perhaps the interpreter is slightly different.

Comment: I tried the == and that worked. Mind you I'm testing on a Fedora 10.10 machine. :)